# How to reduce the length of regular expression

Tags: regex, pcre

I am using the following regular expression and i need to reduce its length while keeping the same behavior.

```
^\s*(John|Matt|Oliver|Tom)\s*(\|\s*(John|Matt|Oliver|Tom)\s*)*$
```

The expression validates a '|' separated list of specific names.

- KD

Comment: If it is PCRE, use `^\s*(John|Matt|Oliver|Tom)\s*(\|\s*(?1)\s*)*$`. If it is Ruby, `\A\s*(John|Matt|Oliver|Tom)\s*(\|\s*\g<1>\s*)*\z`

Comment: You didn't specify a language, but you could have some code insert the delimited names in for you. Depending on how you insert the names in, it may be shorter. Would be future proof anyways.

Comment: Wiktor (?1) was what i was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a PCRE regex, use a [subroutine call](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) `(?1)` in order not to repeat the whole Group 1 subpattern:

```
^\s*(John|Matt|Oliver|Tom)\s*(\|\s*(?1)\s*)*$
                                   ^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PcGVBY/1).

Comment: The regular works fine in C# but if i use it in C its not working correctly :(

Comment: No, this pattern will never work in C#, it will only work in PCRE (PHP, e.g.). In C, if you use `<regex.h>`, you cannot "shorten" the pattern anyway. Use PCRE with C.

Comment: Hello @WiktorStribiżew I have a Google Sheet RE I'd like to reduce but not sure how to do it. Here it is:
`=REGEXREPLACE(JOIN("|",SPLIT(L3,"|")), "((?i)^[A-Z]{1,}|(?i)^[A-Z]{1,}\|)|((?i)^[A-Z]{1,}[a-z]{1,}|(?i)^[A-Z]{1,}[a-z]{1,}\|)|(?i)^([a-z]{1,}[a-z]{0,})|(?i)([A-Z]{1,}[a-z]{0,}(-|\s){0,}[A-Z]{1,}[a-z]{0,})|(?i)([A-Z]{1,}[a-z]{0,})",".+$0.+")` . How can I reduce it? There must be some trimable redundancy but I'm not sure where to begin to trim it.

Comment: For the context, I will use it with a `QUERY` with `MATCHES` formula for use as a `CONTAINS` within the `QUERY` with `|` separated values wraped with `.+$0.+` in cell `L3`.

Comment: @Lod RE2 is not compatible with PCRE. You cannot use subroutines there. What you can do to reduce this is to replace `{1,}` with `+`, and `(-|\s)` with `[-\s]`, `{0,}`  with `*`, and do not use `(?i)` many times, just at the start of the pattern. It is a good idea to edit your pattern in a text editor splitting each alternative on a separate line, you will see if they are similar and if you can shrink the pattern even further.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks again for the suggestions. I could reduce it as per your remarks to that: `REGEXREPLACE(JOIN("|",SPLIT(L3,"|")), "(?i)(^[A-Z]*(|\|))|([A-Z]*[-\s]*[A-Z]*)|([A-Z]*)",".+$0.+")`. For now I think it's as far as I can go. Just a last request. Do you see another way to express this part `(|\|)`?

Comment: @Lod `(|\|)` = `\|?` as it matches a `|` char or an empty string.